# how to detect device connect on android?

Tags: android

I want to detect my connected device using an app on android.

I want to detect a keyboard, mouse, and flash drive.

I am currently using the `hwinfo` command and Timer

```
//keyboard detect class.
public class detectService extends Service {

    static Process hwinfo;
    static String keyboard = "";
    private Handler handler;
    private Timer timer;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       handler = new Handler();

       TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               handler.post(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       String[] cmd = new String[] {"su", "-c", "hwinfo --keyboard | grep - i 'keyboard'"};
                       try {
                            hwinfo = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(hwinfo.getInputStream()));
                            String line;

                            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                               line = line.trim().toLowerCase();

                               keyboard = line;
                               break;
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (keyboard.contains("keyboard")) {
                            timer.cancel();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(this, keyboardDialog.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                     }
                  });
                }
             };
             timer = new Timer("Service");
             timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0 , 4000);
          }
```

This source code detects the keyboard just fine.
But it executes every 4 second.

I want to not use a Timer when I connect a keyboard, mouse, and flash drive.

Detect devices connected on android.

Event detect, or receiver.

How to not use Timer for detecting devices connected on android?

Answer (score 3):

I am going to illustrate USB device detection code. Hope, it will help you.

Step 1 : **To ask for permission to access the USB port, which is done in our manifest file like:**

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
```

Step 2 : **USB configuration in the Manifest file**

```
<activity  
android:name="yourPackageName.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:launchMode="singleInstance">
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data  android:name=
    "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />    
<meta-data android:name=
    "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
</activity>
```

Step 3 : **Create file under res/xml and name it device_filter**

paste below code in it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<resources>  
<!-- 0x0403 / 0x6001: FTDI FT232R UART -->
<usb-device vendor-id="1027" product-id="24577" />
<!-- 0x2341 / Arduino -->
<usb-device vendor-id="9025" />
</resources>
```

Step 4 : **Security and user permission to connect to a USB device**

Since our App does not know if the user has already granted permission, we need to check the user permission flag always, every time that we want to start a USB connection:

```
void checkUSB(){  
  UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
  // Get the list of attached devices
  HashMap<String, UsbDevice> devices = manager.getDeviceList();                
  // Iterate over all devices
  Iterator<String> it = devices.keySet().iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
   String deviceName = it.next();
   UsbDevice device = devices.get(deviceName);
   String VID = Integer.toHexString(device.getVendorId()).toUpperCase();
   String PID = Integer.toHexString(device.getProductId()).toUpperCase();
    if (!manager.hasPermission(device)) {
      private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION  = "yourPackageName.USB_PERMISSION"; 
   PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
   manager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
   return;
} else {
   ... //user permission already granted; prceed to access USB device   
   }
 }
}
```

That's it!!
Happy Coding :-)

Comment: thanks, what is `vender-id` and `product-id` ? why 1027 number?

Comment: it will restrict the type of devices that will trigger your Activity. For more device types you can visit  https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/blob/master/usbSerialExamples/src/main/res/xml/device_filter.xml